# hibernate- querying for rows, with distinct pair of values from two columns

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x

I have a table like:

```
id|column_1|column_2|column_3|
 0|   A    |   100  |   10   |
 1|   B    |   100  |   20   |
 2|   C    |   1000 |   10   |
 3|   D    |   100  |   10   |
```

and i want to query such that i want distinct(column_2 and column_3), means **combination of column_2 and column_3 have to be distinct**. So the result I want is like:

```
id|column_1|column_2|column_3|
 0|   A    |   100  |   10   |
 1|   B    |   100  |   20   |
 2|   C    |   1000 |   10   |
```

I'm using STS MVC & hibernate4, with mysql. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Code I'm using right now is:

```
Session ses=sf.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria=ses.createCriteria(myclass.class);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("column_2"));
projList.add(Projections.property("column_3"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
```

but its just returning the distinct values, i want the complete row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select column1, column2, column3 from table group by column2, column3
```

Regards, 
Arun

Comment: thanks for the help @Abertil, but sorry it's not the answer. The query just returns the grouped data (based on the specified columns). Requirement is to obtain rows based on **distinct pair of values**.
also, m not looking for query, looking for hibernate codes.